# How do make your shiny web app mobile friendly?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I built a shiny dashboard using bs4Dash library. Problem is when I try to use it on phone it looks weird and most of widget gets hidden.
On desktop it is like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpJzl.png)

On phone it is like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcBVq.png)

Is there something I could do to make it look appropriately on phone?

Comment: Hi Mausam, check out this package https://rinterface.github.io/shinyMobile/